# Counting specific values within Python Dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, input

Trying to count the amount of times a specific value occurs within a Python dictionary but can't seem to get it to work.

My dictionary is set up as so:

> count = ({'John': 2, 'Sam': 1, 'Brian': 2, 'Brian': 2, 'Brian': 1, 'Sam': 2,
>   'John': 2, 'Henry': 2, 'Brian': 1})

I am to get the result so that if a user inputs 'Brian' the result would be:

> 4

Or if the user were to enter 'Sam' the result would then be:

> 2

```
number = 0
userInput = input("Please enter a player:  ")
for k, v in count.items():
        if k == userInput:
            number =+ 1
print(number)
```

Is there a better way of doing this, as currently if were to type in 'Sam' it would only output '1'?
Thanks !

Comment: Print out your dictionary, to see your problem. Keys are unique in dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary can have a key only once.
When you create `count = ({'John': 2, 'Sam': 1, 'Brian': 2, 'Brian': 2, 'Brian': 1, 'Sam': 2, 'John': 2, 'Henry': 2, 'Brian': 1})`, Python stores `{'John': 2, 'Brian': 1, 'Sam': 2, 'Henry': 2}` (values can change as there is no rule on what value to keep for a key which appears more than once). Cf [the Python documentation for dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

So the count will always be 1.

If you want to have a key multiple times, don't use a dictionary but a list of pairs (tuples of size 2).

Answer (score 1):

Since python dictionaries must have unique keys, counting how many times a key occurs wont work here. You can read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for more comprehensive details about this data structure.

Furthermore, You can store counts for each name in a dictionary:

```
counts = {'Brian': 4, 'John': 2, 'Sam': 2, 'Henry': 1}
```

Then call each key to obtain the count value:

```
>>> counts['Brian']
4
>>> counts['Sam']
2
```

You could also just keep the names as a list, and call [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count how many times a name occurs:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> names = ['John', 'Sam', 'Brian', 'Brian', 'Brian', 'Sam', 'John', 'Henry', 'Brian']
>>> Counter(names)
Counter({'Brian': 4, 'John': 2, 'Sam': 2, 'Henry': 1})
```

Which returns a `Counter()` object, a subclass of `dict`.